# DynamoDB Mapper not working

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have set up at DynamoDB within AWS and I have a JSP Project which uses the mapper to map to java objects. However when I try and load any data from the tables or save any data to them it doesnt work. I am creating my User and then connectint to the DB and then setting the region and creating the mapper with the client and then saving the user.

```
Users newUser = new Users();
newUser.setUsername(request.getParameter("email"));
newUser.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstname"));
newUser.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastname"));
newUser.setPassword(request.getParameter("pass"));
newUser.setID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
//newUser.setID("0002");
//TODO Add new user to DB and set ID

BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("*********","************");          
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
mapper.save(newUser);
```

From what I have read this should work but when I run the code the Users gets populated but never gets saved in the table. Here is the user class for the mappings

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Users")
public class Users {

    private String Username;
    private String Password;
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private String ID;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Email")
    public String getUsername() { return Username; }
    public void setUsername(String newUsername) { Username = newUsername; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "FirstName")
    public String getFirstName() { return FirstName; }
    public void setFirstName(String newFirstName) { FirstName = newFirstName; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "LastName")
    public String getLastName() { return LastName; }
    public void setLastName(String newLastName) { LastName = newLastName; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Password")
    public String getPassword() { return Password; }
    public void setPassword(String newPassword) { Password = newPassword; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "UserID")
    public String getID() { return ID; }
    public void setID(String newID) { ID = newID; }
}
```

My table has

- Email
- FirstName
- LastName
- Password
- UserID

in it. Does anyone know why i cant save or load any data from it?

Comment: Does the authentication goes fine?

Comment: Yes it  creates the client and the mapper fine. It doesnt even throw any errors when you call save.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it isn't being saved? I find it hard to believe it would silently fail. Is the "Users" table completely empty?

Comment: @mbaird so after a few days of debugging the credentials are not being set to the ones I pass in as a param. They are being set to something else. I have changed the credentials file to the correct keys. However it still sets it to something else. Is there another place where these keys could have been saved?

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of you doing a save and a load and exactly what is happening? Are you looking at the table in the AWS console? How do you know the data isn't being saved?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I might have the same problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the DynamoDB endpoint URL hasn't been specified yet. Please set the endpoint value in client object. Endpoint URL must be specified, even if we are using local DynamoDB (e.g. localhost:8000).

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
client.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8000");
client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
```

Additional note, it seems that you are using deprecated way of instantiating a DynamoDB client object. The following way is preferred, esp. if you are using the latest AWS DynamoDB SDK.

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                        new BasicAWSCredentials("*********", "************")))
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                        "http://localhost:8000",
                        Regions.US_WEST_2.getName()))
                .build();
```